# Why Java is still used in web development?

Tags: java

Why Java is still used in web development? I'm just curious..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267768/java-still-relevant-for-web-programming

Comment: -1 Start programming holy war

Comment: It's a fair question in my opinion. Not asking for opinions but for reasons why we'd still use something that's quite old and well-proven.

Comment: Even if it's a valid question, it might be on the wrong site — "reasons for using Java in web development" sounds more like SO stuff, doesn't it? (Although I'm a little curious about what exactly did OP mean - is he also thinking Web Start & Applet stuff like some of the answerers seem to have done, or actual server-side *web* development...)

Comment: I think it's more of both. Developing in Java is definitely SO stuff. Using applications written in Java is more for SU. This Q is a little of both.

Comment: @Alex, Yeah, but when using web apps/sites created using Java the user generally doesn't even know it's done in Java! So not much to talk about from user's perspective, hence -> SO. Or, if this really is about using Java (Swing etc) applications (deployed over web), then the question is poorly formulated...

Comment: It's about computers and/or computer software, without being about consoles.  It fits here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of reasons:
1. It is by no means a dead language.  There are thousands of Java developers out there.
2. Many available Java developers means that it relatively easy to find maintenance programmers if necessary.
3. The Java / J2EE architecture is robust and reasonably elegant.  It makes it possible to architect well built applications.
4. The free tools available for it are enterprise ready.  For example, Apache / Tomcat / JBoss are a solid foundation to build a web-app from.
5. Excellent support for developers.  Eclipse is one of the best developer platforms available.  Ant and Maven support for Java is excellent.
6. There is a good availability of third-party (and open-source) libraries and Eclipse plug-ins for most of the additional functionality that might be needed but does not come in the core libraries.
7. There is also great support tools from commercial vendors: ORacle; IBM / Rational; etc.
8. Updated versions with newer language constructs are constantly being developed.

In short, it is a good tool for the job.  It is compares favourably to other development platforms (.Net, Ruby, etc), and perhaps is better than some.

Comment: +1 for the first answer that actually makes a lot of sense. I agree about most points, especially about tools, developer support and libraries. Also, "thousands of Java developers" seems an understatement. :) I'm not 100% sure but in my understading there may be more Java developers out there than developers for any other language.

Comment: I'd like to note that the discrepency devs have with j\Java is the langauge itself.  Compared to shiny languages like C#, Objective-C or C++ - it sucks (think lack of class proporties, verbatim strings and lambda's)  Java 8 will take care of some issues, but it'll take some time before it's well adopted. Luckly, there are JVM language's java devs can flock to (Scala/Groovy).  Scala is my personal favorite and it's pretty easy to integrate it with an existing java project.

Answer (score 3):

Simple.  It's a cross platform environment, that is clearly defined, and controlled.  Sure, Sun has a big deal of say in what is available in the Java environment, but there is plenty of 3rd party support and development in the Java environment.

Yes, Java applications start up slightly slower than Native applications, but take a look at VUZE...  Once it's started, it's nearly native speed (or at least it was when I was using it).  With the JIT (Just in Time) compilers, code caching, and other features, there isn't much of a reason that there would be a major speed penalty...

Comment: I'd like to point out the same thing as in Mar Stich's answer: it seems you're talking about end users running Java apps - but, more commonly, users of *Java-based web applications* just use a browser and need never know about how the site is implemented

Answer (score 2):

One big reason I think is because it's platform independent meaning they can easily run on all operating systems as long as you have the Java Runtime Environment installed.  This could allow you to, for example, compile code in Windows and deploy on Unix.

Comment: Of course, when talking about Java and its most common use in web development (i.e. creating web applications), we should remember that it's irrelevant whether *users* have JRE installed

Answer (score 1):

I would also add that while this is only a con against .Net, your application server doesn't have to be Windows so it is cheaper to throw more hardware at it.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason as why COBOL and FORTRAN still exist. Because the language has proven itself to be robust and reliable.

Compare it with cars. Some people want the latest models because it has more power, better speed, improved features and whatever more. Others will just use a reliable car that's made to last for many years without much need for additional maintenance. Some buy a new car every 3 years, others will use their cars for half a century or more.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about Java & the web, people seem to happily mix things by concentrating on Java applications deployed with Web Start (or even Applets), and forgetting that Java is a common language for implementing plain old dynamic web sites (or [web applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application)). The latter is especially true for larger, more "enterprisey" systems. Even if on the desktop Java never really took off, on the server side it certainly did.

Without going into much detail, a couple of reasons why Java is used for creating web sites / applications:

- It's a tried and true approach for building large-scale web apps. Either using just the basic (Java EE) technologies of [Servlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) and [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), or newer frameworks built on top of those, such as [JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/), [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) or [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). (Just one example of high scalability: [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) is implemented in Java, using Google Web Toolkit.)
- A mind-boggling amount of Java libraries exist, for all kinds of tasks — both open-source and commercial ones. If you need some in the backend of your app it may make a lot of sense to do the whole app using the same technology.
- There are *a lot* of skilled Java developers out there — something that may affect tech desicions when launching (larger) projects
- When creating a web interface for, or integrating into, an existing Java enterprise system (which are common) it may be beneficial to use the same language

Edit: I also agree with [Doug](https://superuser.com/questions/24698/why-java-is-still-used-in-web-development/24749#24749) about the tools and developer support. For example, [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) may well be the most advanced IDE *for any language* (and I've heard this also from people who've used Eclipse and Visual Studio extensively... ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

It's ubiquitous.  The tools are great across the board.  It's powerful.  The community is huge.  There is an amazing amount of available libraries / products / toolkits / frameworks.  The JVM is great.

Answer (score 1):

You can build cathedrals with this language.  Those tend to stand for centuries.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java doesn't run on the iPad, doesn't that hurt Java web development?  Developing a web application that supports desktop and mobile is a possible path, but if your site uses Java or Flash, you have eliminated that opportunity.

We have a web application that is for both desktop and mobile (supports swiping, zooming, and such using jQuery).  We decided against Java, Flash, and Silverlight because they do not work with iPad.  The iPad is a growing base and web applications will have to keep up to support it.

It will be interesting to see how this affects web development with Java... time will tell.

Comment: Java is widely used in **the backend**, and you are only talking about the frontend